# Метка за опрос не присвоена на аккаунт Stack Overflow на русском

Tags: поддержка

Несколько дней назад я прошел ежегодный опрос разработчиков, и мне дали метку Census на аккаунт Stack Overflow. Захожу на русский сайт - метки нет. Как получить ее на оба аккаунта?

Comment: Пройти опросник и в руссом SO :)